# SSL issues in chromium browser clientside

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl, chromium, steam

So for the last couple of days I've been having a strange issue trying to navigate specifically to the Steam Community, in either Google Chrome or in the Steam Client itself.

Right after booting up windows 10 (1903) I can navigate in to the Steam Community just fine in any browser, but after an undermined amount of time, generally watching youtube, browsing and playing games, the steam community will become inaccessible to me due to an SSL.

Originally the error was:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID Subject:
>   4kuhd.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com
>
> Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
>
> Expires on: Aug 5, 2020
>
> Current date: May 8, 2020

This is very suspicious to me given that it is listing sony entertainment, to which I have no known associations.

Trying again today however I receive either ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Regardless of this all, in Firefox and Edge I can access it just fine.
I have already cleared the SSL state repeatedly, and browsed it to see if I could find the described address, but I could not find any reference to it or steamcommunity.com.

**Edit 1:** Removing the Google Chrome User Data folder does not solve this for as far as I can immediately tell. Additionally, my system runs ESET Internet Security 13.1.21.0, disabling the associated firewall and other protective services don't make a difference for as far as I can tell.

**Edit 2:** Despite my doubting it would make a difference, clearing my windows Hosts file has ended up fixing, it, weirder still, reinstating the old hosts file (which is quite extensive) did not cause it to break again. Assuming the issue does not return, this might be the sollution.

Any idea why this might be happening, especially given that it happens only after a certain period after booting up?

Comment: If you backups then delete your Chrome user profile are you able to recreate the problem?  What security software do you have installed?

Comment: I'll update the question to answer that.

Comment: Do you have ESET configured to scan secure traffic?  I highly suspect ESET is the problem, and simply disabling it, wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, I found something noteworthy just now, updated the question.

Comment: What modified the HOSTS file?

Comment: I did, I've used it to block several locations that are known to be related to malware and/or ads. However, it turns out that something in it, messes with specifically the SSL certificates for the Steam Community, on only chromium-based browsers, and only after a certain period after booting up.

Comment: Thank you sir. i have same problem, steam is blocked in my country before so i edited the hosts file, and after some time steam is allowed and i can't access steam community.  it turns out because i forgot to restore my hosts file XD